# Windows 8.1 Bing map control

Tags: c#, xaml, bing-maps, windows-8.1

I have added the bing map reference and name space but when I drag and drop the map control to my designer it give me an error.

A reference to "Bing.Maps.Xaml, Version=1.313.0825.0" has been added to the project.In Order to use types from the new reference,Press ok to restart the XAML Designer. After 
the XAML Designer restarts, Re-create the control on the artboard.

I have restarted the xaml designer and tried new project but all in vein.

Answer (score 2):

in vs2013, Select BUILD from the main menu, then Configuration Manager. 
Choose x86 its done

Comment: Yeah, VS is 32bit, i had the mentioned problem with my own assembly. Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

Create an app with Bing Maps (for Windows 8.1) [read msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn456475.aspx).

Comment: I have double checked that

Answer (score 1):

I think you can download http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Windows-8-Modern-Style-App-Samples samples (it contains 200 samples for "Windows 8.1").

And you can have a look what BingMap app sample does thing different than your app (and also maybe you can try to add sample's dll to your application, there could be a version difference.)

Comment: thanks, its windows 8.1 app not 8 and these samples are useless for me

Comment: It was my fault I wrote there Windows 8 but the link that I gave to you getting you to Windows 8.1 samples. If you have a look you'll see!